Alignment issue in table from HTML to PDF
Using Flying Saucer 9.1.18 (flying-saucer-pdf) to generate PDF from HTML/xml to PDF file in my java program.
I noticed that if I open the input xml in the browser, the text (Lorem ipsum etc) is all left aligned. However in the generated PDF, the text is all centered.
The 2  has no align attribute and the browser is taking the default of left alignment. However the PDF seem to inherit this from the TD containing the parent table. Is this an expected behavior ?
<body style="height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;background-color:#dddddd;">    
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="body-table" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#dddddd;border:1px solid purple;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" id="body-cell" style="height:100%;margin:0;width:100%;padding:0;">        
       <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="email-body" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:separate;border:1px solid blue;">    
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%">
           <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td id="email-letter" style="background-color:#edf4fd;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-right:30px;padding-left:30px;">
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="540" style="border:1px solid green;">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>                
                   <td style="padding-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;line-height:150%;">Lorem ipsum</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td style="font-size:14px;line-height:150%;">Praesent libero dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br /><br /> Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa.  <p></p> </td>
                 </tr>                
                </tbody>
               </table> </td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table> </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
    </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
 </body>

The HTML comes from marketing and we won't be able to change it unfortunately.
Also, is there any licensing requirement using this version for a commercial product? The PDF generation is only a very small feature. TIA!

Questions about commercial issues and licencing are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Also don't make multiple questions into one.

You may not change the source document but you could transform it before converting it to PDF.

I need help on how can we transform it?
